# openssl_encrypt does not return anything

Tags: php

```
function encrypt($text,$key){

    $method = 'AES-256-CBC';
    $size = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
    $iv = substr($key, 0, $size);
    $openssl = openssl_encrypt($text, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
    return base64_encode($openssl);

}
```

This method does not return anything, I am just trying to write a reliable encryption function using openssl.

Comment: At the least you should verify how far you are getting in your own code, and if any of the results are expected. SO is a terrible debugger. What debugging have you tried?

Answer (score -1):

Correct syntax is

```
$openssl = openssl_encrypt($text, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA || OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, do not do it that way! For the combination of the flags the bitwise operator `|` *must* be used and *not* the logical operator `||`. Using `||` generally gives unexpected results.

Comment: The failed encryption is not due to `|`, but to the `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` flag itself. This flag disables the default PKCS#7 padding (and does nothing else, in particular no Zero padding is enabled), which generally results in an error for a block cipher mode like CBC. The fix is to either not set that flag at all for a block cipher mode, or if it is set, to implement another padding *explicitly* (what does not happen in the code).

Comment: When using `||`, the problem is only *supposedly* solved: `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA || OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` gives `true` because `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA = 1` and `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING = 2`, which is converted to `1` and thus corresponds to `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA`, i.e. `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` is simply ignored.